# ESXi - Forward port to virtual machine?

Tags: networking, routes, virtual-machine, esxi

For example, i have a ESXi Host with a router vm and a intern network.

Could i use the host ip for other things except ESXi?

I mean: On a virtual machine is a webserver (port 80).

**Could i route the port 80 from esxi host to the Virtual Machine Port 80?**

Image:
http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=esxinhxgi.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a second ip adress. Then i created a router vm in a subnetwork and then i could give different machines different ports...